# cannot access zzbql class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbql not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new with firebase,

I am trying to use FirebaseAuth but in some reason, this gave me this error:

> "Error:(27, 36) error: cannot access zzbql class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbql not found"

This is the source code:

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference usersReference;

private User currentUser;

public ModelUserFirebase() {
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    usersReference = database.getReference(USERS_KEY);
}
```

This is the gradle files:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you please post your full build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

try to update all firebase library dependencies to 11.0.2 version

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in some reason only removing all the firebase settings from the project and install it again works fine

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I just updated the Firebase Auth dependency in Gradel (app) file to 11.0.4

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem like you.
I use :
- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
- compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
After I change 11.6.0 => 11.4.2 then it work normal.
Hope that help you.